# How to create download feature using ASP.NET Core 2.1 and React JS?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, reactjs, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core and React JS. I'm newbie to this both platforms. I have used Axios for requesting data and getting response from server. But I have not requested images or any kind of file from server. This time I'm working on Download feature where user will click on button and can download desired file which is of .png, .jpg, .pdf format. I'm not understanding how can server will send data? I read, I needed to send base64 data which is converted from blob format. But not understanding how to request data from client and how server will serve desired file. In DB, I have stored only address of file e.g. /images/img1.jpg. This file actually resides in wwwroot/images folder. I have used [downloadjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/downloadjs) for downloading which is working correctly but after downloading, that image is not readable as it does not have any content.

Please anyone help me to implement this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need API to download data something like this

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string filename)  
  {  
      if (filename == null)  
          return Content("filename not present");  

      var path = Path.Combine(  
                     Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),  
                     "wwwroot", filename);  

      var memory = new MemoryStream();  
      using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))  
      {  
          await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);  
      }  
      memory.Position = 0;  
      return File(memory, GetContentType(path), Path.GetFileName(path));  
  } 

private string GetContentType(string path)  
    {  
        var types = GetMimeTypes();  
        var ext = Path.GetExtension(path).ToLowerInvariant();  
        return types[ext];  
    }  

    private Dictionary<string, string> GetMimeTypes()  
    {  
        return new Dictionary<string, string>  
        {  
            {".txt", "text/plain"},  
            {".pdf", "application/pdf"},  
            {".doc", "application/vnd.ms-word"},  
            {".docx", "application/vnd.ms-word"},  
            {".xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel"},  
            {".xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats  
officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"},  
                {".png", "image/png"},  
                {".jpg", "image/jpeg"},  
                {".jpeg", "image/jpeg"},  
                {".gif", "image/gif"},  
                {".csv", "text/csv"}  
            };  
        }
```

Then download file like this

```
axios({
  url: 'your url',
  method: 'POST',       // Worked using POST or PUT. Prefer POST
  responseType: 'blob', // important
}).then((response) => {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
});
```

Ref [link](https://gist.github.com/javilobo8/097c30a233786be52070986d8cdb1743)

Comment: Thank you for showing direction. Code after making changes from this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-download-files-in-asp-net-core-2-0/) i.e. definition of `GetContentType(path)` I have found in this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-download-files-in-asp-net-core-2-0/). But I'm facing one issue. This code works perfectly on localhost. But when I upload on server then it's throwing an error of Status code 400. I tried everything but couldn't resolve that issue. How can I fix that error?

Comment: which host service you are using?

Comment: My website is running on IIS server and running on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: you can create another question so i can take a look at

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131868/throwing-error-while-downloading-file-in-asp-net-core-with-status-code-400) I have created new question.