# Throwing error while downloading file in ASP.NET Core with status code 400

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, axios

I'm working on download feature. When I run code on localhost, it runs perfectly without any error. But when I uploads same code to server then it returns `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)` error in console of browser. For requesting and getting response from server, I have used Axios. I'm newbie to ASP.NET Core + ReactJS technology stack  and working on APIs for the first time so it's being difficult for me to figuring out root cause of this error.

Here is my code for requesting data from server.

```
axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/ImageFetch/ImageFetchPoint',
        responseType: 'blob',// important
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: filepath
    }).then(function(response) {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));

        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Status:", error.response.status);
        console.log("Data:", error.response.data);
    });
```

For getting response as file(any extension) from server, I've used following code.

```
    [HttpPost("PanImageFunction")]
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ImageFetchFunction([FromBody] ImageFetchRequest request)
    {
        var filePath = request.ImagePath;
        var filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        string path="unknownpath";
        try {
            if (filename == null)
                return Content("filename not present");

            path = Path.Combine(
                       Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                       "RegistrationImages", filename);

        } catch(Exception ex) {
            new Logger().write(ex);
        }

        var memory = new MemoryStream();
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
        }
        System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
        {
            FileName = filename,
            Inline = false  // false = prompt the user for downloading;  true = browser to try to show the file inline
        };

        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
        Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");

        memory.Position = 0;
        return File(memory, GetContentType(path), Path.GetFileName(path));
    }

    private string GetContentType(string path)
    {
        var types = GetMimeTypes();
        var ext = Path.GetExtension(path).ToLowerInvariant();
        return types[ext];
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> GetMimeTypes()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {".txt", "text/plain"},
            {".pdf", "application/pdf"},
            {".doc", "application/vnd.ms-word"},
            {".docx", "application/vnd.ms-word"},
            {".xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel"},  
            {".png", "image/png"},
            {".jpg", "image/jpeg"},
            {".jpeg", "image/jpeg"},
            {".gif", "image/gif"},
            {".csv", "text/csv"}
        };
    }
```

Complete code works perfectly on localhost. But when I uploads it on server then it throws 400 bad request error on console of browser as you can see in following image.

[image]

I have checked many forums and articles but most of the articles related to ASP.NET core giving solution related to Razor pages and not giving solutions related to ReactJS and Axios.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Please check the server logs to see why it is returning a 400 response. Also, you might want to check the response in the network tab of your browser’s developer tools to see if there was any response body with the 400 that explains the error.

Comment: How did you host .net core? Try to enable [ASP.NET Core Module stdout log (IIS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-2.2#aspnet-core-module-stdout-log-iis) and share us the server side error. Try to restart .net core application to avoid cache issue. What is the value for `filepath`.